# ChannelHandler.exceptionCaught semantics

Tags: java, netty

I was wondering if the implied semantics of this method is that it's invoked at most once on a given handler? For example, `handlerRemoved` defines this very clearly:

> Gets called after the ChannelHandler was removed from the actual context and **it doesn't handle events anymore**.

Thanks.

Comment: Quoting the Javadoc: "Gets called if a Throwable was thrown.". This implies that if no exception is thrown, it won't be called.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, that's clear. I'm interested whether there are cases when `exceptionCaught` is called more than once. For example if you have a look at [reactive-streams](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/) `onError` has a semantics of a terminal invocation. i.e. it's the last invocation on a `Subscriber`.

Answer (score 0):

It can called multiple times as whenever you can recover from an error or not is up to the user code.